# optimize SELECT {OTHER_COLUMNS} IN MAX....GROUP BY statement

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, max, subquery

I am familar with the problems MySQL has if you issue a query like this:

```
SELECT `user_log`.`USER_NAME`, MAX(`user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`), `user_log`.`COMPUTER_NAME`, `user_log`.`LOCATION`  
    FROM `user_log` 
    GROUP BY `user_log`.`USER_NAME` 
    ORDER BY `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME` DESC
```

This will not return the COMPUTER_NAME and LOCATION associated with the MAX ACCESS_DATE_TIME, like you would think. It will return the first value in the set that is defined by your GROUP BY column (All of USER_NAME).

So to get around this, I am attempting to construct a query that links up the MAX...GROUP BY sql, with one that selects all the columns I need, where the USER_NAME and ACCESS_DATE_TIME fall into the set that gets grabbed user the MAX...GROUP statement.

This is what I have ->

```
SELECT `user_log`.`USER_NAME`, `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`, `user_log`.`COMPUTER_NAME`, `user_log`.`LOCATION` 
FROM `user_log`.`user_log` 
JOIN (SELECT `user_log`.`USER_NAME`, MAX(`user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`) as sub_max 
    FROM `user_log` 
    GROUP BY `USER_NAME` 
    ORDER BY sub_max DESC) as sub
WHERE (`user_log`.`USER_NAME` = sub.`USER_NAME` AND `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME` = sub.sub_max)
```

However, it is not very fast....is there a better way to do this? I'm sure that someone has come up with something by now...

Answer (score 1):

Compare the performance to a temporary table instead (untested):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `user_log_temp` ENGINE=memory
SELECT `user_log`.`USER_NAME`, MAX(`user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`) as sub_max 
FROM `user_log` 
GROUP BY `USER_NAME`;

SELECT `user_log`.`USER_NAME`, `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`, `user_log`.`COMPUTER_NAME`, `user_log`.`LOCATION` 
FROM `user_log`.`user_log` 
JOIN `user_log_temp` as sub 
  ON `user_log`.`USER_NAME` = sub.`USER_NAME`
  AND `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME` = sub.sub_max;

DROP TABLE `user_log_temp`;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up implementing ->

To create the table with MAX...GROUP BY relations ->

```
CREATE TABLE `user_log_max`
   SELECT
     `USER_NAME`, 
      /* Alias this calculated value as ACCESS_DATE_TIME */
      MAX(`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`) AS `ACCESS_DATE_TIME` 
   FROM `user_log`
   GROUP BY `USER_NAME`
```

To grab all the data ->

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user_log`.`COMPUTER_NAME`, `user_log`.`LOCATION`, `user_log`.`USER_NAME`, `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME` 
FROM `user_log`, `user_log_max`
WHERE `user_log_max`.`USER_NAME` = `user_log`.`USER_NAME` AND `user_log_max`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME ` = `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`
```

Make sure to add proper indexes, because otherwise it will still be slow.

You can also drop the table when you are done, if you want since it won't be relevent as time goes on ->

```
DROP TABLE `user_log_max`
```